# decorators in the python standard lib (@deprecated specifically)

Tags: python, decorator, deprecated

I need to mark routines as deprecated, but apparently there's no standard library decorator for deprecation. I am aware of recipes for it and the warnings module, but my question is: why is there no standard library decorator for this (common) task ?

Additional question: are there standard decorators in the standard library at all ?

Comment: now there is a [deprecation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/deprecation) package

Comment: I understand the ways to do it, but came here for some insight on why it's not in the std lib (as I assume is the case of the OP) and don't see a good answer to the actual question

Comment: Why does it happen so often that questions get dozens of answers that don't even attempt to answer the question, and actively ignore things like "I'm aware of recipes"? It's maddening!

Comment: @Catskul because of fake internet points.

Comment: The OP rules out `warnings.warn`, but for those who aren't aware of it, I prefer it to anything found here for deprecation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9008488/733092

Comment: @Catskul Aren't *why* questions deprecated at all or shouldn't they be on SO? As we see so often, they tend to produce nonanswers. I would not have left this comment if I had not seen all your *doesn't answer* decorators 

Comment: I'm unaware of any ruling against "why" questions, but IMO lots of "why" questions are likely to have a succinct answer, and the question/answers can be important so I'd be sad if they were disallowed.

Comment: Watch https://peps.python.org/pep-0702/ (slated for python 3.12)

Answer (score 94):

Here's some snippet, modified from those cited by Leandro:

```
import warnings
import functools

def deprecated(func):
    """This is a decorator which can be used to mark functions
    as deprecated. It will result in a warning being emitted
    when the function is used."""
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
        warnings.simplefilter('always', DeprecationWarning)  # turn off filter
        warnings.warn("Call to deprecated function {}.".format(func.__name__),
                      category=DeprecationWarning,
                      stacklevel=2)
        warnings.simplefilter('default', DeprecationWarning)  # reset filter
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return new_func

# Examples

@deprecated
def some_old_function(x, y):
    return x + y

class SomeClass:
    @deprecated
    def some_old_method(self, x, y):
        return x + y
```

Because in some interpreters the first solution exposed (without filter handling) may result in a warning suppression.

Comment: Why not use `functools.wraps` rather than setting the name and doc like that?

Comment: @Maximilian: Edited to add that, to save future copy-pasters of this code from doing it wrong too

Comment: I do not like side effect (turning the filter on / off). It's not the job of the decorator to decide this.

Comment: Turning the filter on and off may trigger http://bugs.python.org/issue29672

Comment: doesn't answer the actual question.

Comment: @Catskul The actual question would likely be subject to closure as being too subjective.

Comment: Strongly agree with @Kentzo - disabling filters then resetting them to defaults is going to give some developer an amazing headache

Comment: Why `stackevel=2` here? What's deprecated is calling `new_func`, not calling the caller of `new_func`. (Note that `new_func` is what's actually called whenever someone calls the function that was decorated.) See the example case of using `stacklevel` in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.warn I don't think it applies here.

Answer (score 83):

Here is another solution:

This decorator (a [decorator factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654) in fact) allow you to give a **reason** message. It is also more useful to help the developer to diagnose the problem by giving the source **filename** and **line number**.

**EDIT**: This code use Zero's recommendation: it replace `warnings.warn_explicit` line by `warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)`,
which prints the function call site rather than the function definition site. It makes debugging easier.

**EDIT2**: This version allow the developper to specify an optional "reason" message.

```
import functools
import inspect
import warnings

string_types = (type(b''), type(u''))


def deprecated(reason):
    """
    This is a decorator which can be used to mark functions
    as deprecated. It will result in a warning being emitted
    when the function is used.
    """

    if isinstance(reason, string_types):

        # The @deprecated is used with a 'reason'.
        #
        # .. code-block:: python
        #
        #    @deprecated("please, use another function")
        #    def old_function(x, y):
        #      pass

        def decorator(func1):

            if inspect.isclass(func1):
                fmt1 = "Call to deprecated class {name} ({reason})."
            else:
                fmt1 = "Call to deprecated function {name} ({reason})."

            @functools.wraps(func1)
            def new_func1(*args, **kwargs):
                warnings.simplefilter('always', DeprecationWarning)
                warnings.warn(
                    fmt1.format(name=func1.__name__, reason=reason),
                    category=DeprecationWarning,
                    stacklevel=2
                )
                warnings.simplefilter('default', DeprecationWarning)
                return func1(*args, **kwargs)

            return new_func1

        return decorator

    elif inspect.isclass(reason) or inspect.isfunction(reason):

        # The @deprecated is used without any 'reason'.
        #
        # .. code-block:: python
        #
        #    @deprecated
        #    def old_function(x, y):
        #      pass

        func2 = reason

        if inspect.isclass(func2):
            fmt2 = "Call to deprecated class {name}."
        else:
            fmt2 = "Call to deprecated function {name}."

        @functools.wraps(func2)
        def new_func2(*args, **kwargs):
            warnings.simplefilter('always', DeprecationWarning)
            warnings.warn(
                fmt2.format(name=func2.__name__),
                category=DeprecationWarning,
                stacklevel=2
            )
            warnings.simplefilter('default', DeprecationWarning)
            return func2(*args, **kwargs)

        return new_func2

    else:
        raise TypeError(repr(type(reason)))
```

You can use this decorator for **functions**, **methods** and **classes**.

Here is a simple example:

```
@deprecated("use another function")
def some_old_function(x, y):
    return x + y


class SomeClass(object):
    @deprecated("use another method")
    def some_old_method(self, x, y):
        return x + y


@deprecated("use another class")
class SomeOldClass(object):
    pass


some_old_function(5, 3)
SomeClass().some_old_method(8, 9)
SomeOldClass()
```

You'll get:

```
deprecated_example.py:59: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function or method some_old_function (use another function).
  some_old_function(5, 3)
deprecated_example.py:60: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function or method some_old_method (use another method).
  SomeClass().some_old_method(8, 9)
deprecated_example.py:61: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated class SomeOldClass (use another class).
  SomeOldClass()
```

**EDIT3:** This decorator is now part of the Deprecated library:

- [Python package index (PyPi)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/deprecated)
- [GitHub website](https://github.com/tantale/deprecated)
- [Read The Docs](http://deprecated.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [Twitter](https://twitter.com/laporte_laurent/status/1154836786323099648?s=20)

New stable release v1.2.13

Comment: Works, well - I prefer replacing the `warn_explicit` line with `warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)` which prints the function call site rather than the function definition site. It makes debugging easier.

Comment: Hello, I would like to use your code snippet in [a GPLv3-licensed library](https://github.com/FIDUCEO/FCDR_HIRS/).  Would you be willing to relicense your code under GPLv3 [or any more permissive license](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/3/33), so that I can legally do so?

Comment: @gerrit: [All user contributions are licensed under Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing).

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE I know.  CC-BY-SO does not permit usage within GPLv3 (because of the share-alike bit), which is why I'm asking if you would be willing to release this code specifically additionally under a GPL-compatible license.  If not, that's fine, and I won't use your code.

Comment: doesn't answer the actual question.

Comment: @gerrit GPL is actual a much less permissive license than most others. In many cases GPL should be avoided.

Comment: @DannyVarod I know, but for code, CC-BY-SA is even more restrictive than GPL.  When I asked the question, I was working on a GPL library.  GPL libraries can use GPL code or more permissive code, but GPL libraries can *not* use CC-BY-SA code, so I was not able to use this code snippet. (And CC-BY-SA was never used for code anyway; SO would do good in licensing code snippets in user contributions under something more permissive, because as it is now, most users cannot use code snippets they find on SO)

Answer (score 32):

[As muon suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536307/how-do-i-deprecate-python-functions#comment81075691_2536307), you can install the [`deprecation`](https://pypi.org/project/deprecation/#description) package for this.

> The `deprecation` library provides a `deprecated` decorator and a `fail_if_not_removed` decorator for your tests.

#### Installation

```
pip install deprecation
```

#### Example Usage

```
import deprecation

@deprecation.deprecated(deprecated_in="1.0", removed_in="2.0",
                        current_version=__version__,
                        details="Use the bar function instead")
def foo():
    """Do some stuff"""
    return 1
```

See http://deprecation.readthedocs.io/ for the full documentation.

Comment: doesn't answer the actual question.

Comment: Note *PyCharm* doesn't recognise this

Answer (score 19):

I guess the reason is that Python code can't be processed statically (as it done for C++ compilers), you can't get warning about using some things before actually using it. I don't think that it's a good idea to spam user of your script with a bunch of messages "Warning: this developer of this script is using deprecated API".

**Update:** but you can create decorator which will transform original function into another. New function will mark/check switch telling that this function was called already and will show message only on turning switch into on state. And/or at exit it may print list of all deprecated functions used in program.

Comment: And you should be able to indicate deprecation **when the function is imported from the module**. Decorator would be a right tool for that.

Comment: @JanuszLenar, that warning will be show even if we don't use that deprecated function. But I guess I can update my answer with some hint.

Answer (score 19):

You can create a utils file

```
import warnings

def deprecated(message):
  def deprecated_decorator(func):
      def deprecated_func(*args, **kwargs):
          warnings.warn("{} is a deprecated function. {}".format(func.__name__, message),
                        category=DeprecationWarning,
                        stacklevel=2)
          warnings.simplefilter('default', DeprecationWarning)
          return func(*args, **kwargs)
      return deprecated_func
  return deprecated_decorator
```

And then import the deprecation decorator as follows:

```
from .utils import deprecated

@deprecated("Use method yyy instead")
def some_method():
 pass
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using this to send the user to the right place instead of just showing the deprecation message!

Comment: doesn't answer the actual question.

Answer (score 19):

A future Python version (after 3.13) will include the [`warnings.deprecated` decorator](https://peps.python.org/pep-0702/) which will indicate deprecations to type checkers like `mypy`.

> As an example, consider this library stub named library.pyi:
>
> ```
> from warnings import deprecated
>
> @deprecated("Use Spam instead")
> class Ham: ...
>
> @deprecated("It is pining for the fiords")
> def norwegian_blue(x: int) -> int: ...
>
> @overload
> @deprecated("Only str will be allowed")
> def foo(x: int) -> str: ...
> @overload
> def foo(x: str) -> str: ...
> ```
>
> Here is how type checkers should handle usage of this library:
>
> ```
> from library import Ham  # error: Use of deprecated class Ham. Use Spam instead.
>
> import library
>
> library.norwegian_blue(1)  # error: Use of deprecated function norwegian_blue. It is pining for the fiords.
> map(library.norwegian_blue, [1, 2, 3])  # error: Use of deprecated function norwegian_blue. It is pining for the fiords.
>
> library.foo(1)  # error: Use of deprecated overload for foo. Only str will be allowed.
> library.foo("x")  # no error
>
> ham = Ham()  # no error (already reported above)
> ```
>
> > Source: [PEP702](https://peps.python.org/pep-0702/)

Comment: @Catskul, maybe this finally answers the question?

Answer (score 1):

`Python` is a **dynamically** typed language. Not necessary declare the type to variable or argument type for function statically.

Since its dynamic every thing if processed at runtime. Even if a method is deprecated it will be known at runtime or during interpretation only.

use [**deprecation**](https://deprecation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#api-documentation) module to deprecate methods.

> deprecation is a library that enables automated deprecations. It
> offers the **[deprecated()](https://deprecation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#deprecation.deprecated)** decorator to wrap functions, providing proper
> warnings both in documentation and via Python’s **[warnings](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/warnings.html#module-warnings)** system, as
> well as the **[deprecation.fail_if_not_removed()](https://deprecation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#deprecation.fail_if_not_removed)** decorator for test
> methods to ensure that deprecated code is eventually removed.

### Installing :

```
python3.10 -m pip install deprecation
```

### Small demonstration:

```
import deprecation

@deprecation.deprecated(details="Use bar instead")
def foo():
    print("Foo")


def bar():
    print("Bar")


foo()

bar()
```

### Output:

```
test.py: DeprecatedWarning: foo is deprecated. Use bar instead
  foo()

Foo

Bar
```

Comment: Python is a dynamically-typed language, but it does have static typing through the `typing`  module. This typing has no effect at runtime; it’s only used by static analysis tools such as `mypy` or editor integrations. I’m downvoting this answer because it suggests a solution that was **explicitely** mentioned as unsatisfying in the question body. Runtime warnings work, but they don’t tell mypy or your editor that this function is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I think is better, when we show DeprecationWarning only first time for **each code line** and when we can send some message:

```
import inspect
import traceback
import warnings
import functools

import time


def deprecated(message: str = ''):
    """
    This is a decorator which can be used to mark functions
    as deprecated. It will result in a warning being emitted
    when the function is used first time and filter is set for show DeprecationWarning.
    """
    def decorator_wrapper(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def function_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            current_call_source = '|'.join(traceback.format_stack(inspect.currentframe()))
            if current_call_source not in function_wrapper.last_call_source:
                warnings.warn("Function {} is now deprecated! {}".format(func.__name__, message),
                              category=DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
                function_wrapper.last_call_source.add(current_call_source)

            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        function_wrapper.last_call_source = set()

        return function_wrapper
    return decorator_wrapper


@deprecated('You must use my_func2!')
def my_func():
    time.sleep(.1)
    print('aaa')
    time.sleep(.1)


def my_func2():
    print('bbb')


warnings.simplefilter('always', DeprecationWarning)  # turn off filter
print('before cycle')
for i in range(5):
    my_func()
print('after cycle')
my_func()
my_func()
my_func()
```

Result:

```
before cycle
C:/Users/adr-0/OneDrive/Projects/Python/test/unit1.py:45: DeprecationWarning: Function my_func is now deprecated! You must use my_func2!
aaa
aaa
aaa
aaa
aaa
after cycle
C:/Users/adr-0/OneDrive/Projects/Python/test/unit1.py:47: DeprecationWarning: Function my_func is now deprecated! You must use my_func2!
aaa
C:/Users/adr-0/OneDrive/Projects/Python/test/unit1.py:48: DeprecationWarning: Function my_func is now deprecated! You must use my_func2!
aaa
C:/Users/adr-0/OneDrive/Projects/Python/test/unit1.py:49: DeprecationWarning: Function my_func is now deprecated! You must use my_func2!
aaa

Process finished with exit code 0
```

We can just click on the warning path and go to the line in PyCharm.

Comment: doesn't answer the actual question.