# lint usages of functions with @deprecated decorator

Tags: python, static-analysis, deprecation-warning

Is there a linter that detects usages of functions that are marked as deprecated with the `@deprecated` decorator from the `deprecated` package?

e.g. in

```py
from deprecated import deprecated

def realfun():
    print('Hey there')

@deprecated(reason="this is a test")
def myfun():
    realfun()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myfun()
```

I will get a runtime warning when running it as `PYTHONWARNINGS="default::DeprecationWarning" python testfile.py` but `pylint`, `mypy`, and `flake8` seem to be (at least how I run them) happy with calling `myfun`.

Comment: This is just a random package that adds warnings. If I were to create a package named `hey`, my linters would not even know about it. What you need to do: 1) either find how linters suggest resolving deprecation (could be another package or a comment. 2) either create a custom rule, lets say for `pylint` and add it to your `.pylintrc`. Check [custom checkers](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/how_tos/custom_checkers.html)

Answer (score 6):

As others have mentioned, you have to write a custom `pylint` checker. The way this works is you define a class that subclasses `pylint`'s `BaseChecker`, and define what warnings to emit and when to emit them.

The following code does exactly that. It's a little tailored to the `deprecated` package's specific keyword arguments, but it should work generally whenever somebody uses a decorator called `deprecated` to mark a function or class, and will issue a `pylint` warning `W0001` (feel free to change it, for example to an error). It should also provide an informative message.

To use it, add the code to a file called (for example) `deprecated_checker.py`, and either add the folder containing `deprecated_checker.py` to the `PYTHONPATH` or add the source to the `pylint/checkers` folder. Then you can lint by running `pylint` with the option `--load-plugins=deprecated_checker`.

For more info on writing your own checkers, [look here](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/how_tos/custom_checkers.html).

```py
from astroid.nodes import Call, ClassDef, FunctionDef, Name
from pylint.checkers import BaseChecker
from pylint.interfaces import IAstroidChecker


class DeprecatedChecker(BaseChecker):
    __implements__ = IAstroidChecker

    name = "no-deprecated"
    priority = -1
    msgs = {
        "W0001": (
            "%s %s is deprecated since version %s; reason: %s.",
            "deprecated",
            "Functions that have been marked via annotations as deprecated should not be used.",
        )
    }

    def __init__(self, linter=None):
        super().__init__(linter)

    def visit_decorators(self, node):
        # Check if there are decorators
        if node.nodes is None:
            return

        # Figure out whether its a class or function
        # that is deprecated, and get relevant info
        if isinstance(node.parent, ClassDef):
            parent_type = "Class"
        elif isinstance(node.parent, FunctionDef):
            parent_type = "Function"
        parent_name = node.parent.name

        # Check each decorator to see if its deprecating
        for decorator in node.get_children():
            if isinstance(decorator, Call):
                if decorator.func.name == "deprecated":
                    version = "(not specified)"
                    reason = "not specified"
                    if decorator.keywords is not None:
                        for kw in decorator.keywords:
                            if kw.arg == "version":
                                version = f'"{kw.value.value}"'
                            if kw.arg == "reason":
                                reason = f'"{kw.value.value}"'
                    self.add_message(
                        "deprecated",
                        node=node.parent,
                        args=(parent_type, parent_name, version, reason),
                    )
            elif isinstance(decorator, Name):
                if decorator.name == "deprecated":
                    self.add_message(
                        "deprecated",
                        node=node.parent,
                        args=(
                            parent_type,
                            parent_name,
                            "(not specified)",
                            "not specified",
                        ),
                    )

def register(linter):
    linter.register_checker(DeprecatedChecker(linter))
```

If you've done all that, then linting the stub file `tmp.py`

```py
from deprecated import deprecated


@deprecated
def fn_stmt():
    pass

@deprecated(version="0.1.0")
def fn_version():
    pass

@deprecated(reason="I'm mean")
def fn_reason():
    pass

@deprecated(version="0.1.0", reason="I'm mean")
def fn_both():
    pass

@deprecated
class ClassStmt:
    pass

@deprecated(version="0.1.0")
class ClassVersion:
    pass

@deprecated(reason="I'm mean")
class ClassReason:
    pass

@deprecated(version="0.1.0", reason="I'm mean")
class ClassBoth:
    pass
```

with the command `pylint --load-plugins=deprecated_checker --disable=all --enable=deprecated tmp.py` will get you

```sh
************* Module tmp
tmp.py:5:0: W0001: Function fn_stmt is deprecated since version (not specified); reason: (not specified). (deprecated)
tmp.py:9:0: W0001: Function fn_version is deprecated since version 0.1.0; reason: (not specified). (deprecated)
tmp.py:13:0: W0001: Function fn_reason is deprecated since version (not specified); reason: I'm mean. (deprecated)
tmp.py:17:0: W0001: Function fn_both is deprecated since version 0.1.0; reason: I'm mean. (deprecated)
tmp.py:20:0: W0001: Class ClassStmt is deprecated since version (not specified); reason: (not specified). (deprecated)
tmp.py:24:0: W0001: Class ClassVersion is deprecated since version 0.1.0; reason: (not specified). (deprecated)
tmp.py:28:0: W0001: Class ClassReason is deprecated since version (not specified); reason: I'm mean. (deprecated)
tmp.py:32:0: W0001: Class ClassBoth is deprecated since version 0.1.0; reason: I'm mean. (deprecated)

-------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 5.29/10 (previous run: -2.35/10, +7.65)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at [How to warn about class (name) deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008444/how-to-warn-about-class-name-deprecation) to add your own rule to lint.  There is no standard library method for marking deprecations, so it won't be built in to the tools.  The closest is a specific class in the `warnings` library.