# Deprecate import from a.py when Class changed from a.py to b.py

Tags: python, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I have a class 'Model' in a.py, Now the class has moved to b.py. So whenever end user use from a import Model, I wanted to through an deprecation or some warning message. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

you should use warning (https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) and more specially DeprecationWarning (https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#DeprecationWarning)

a good answer already exist here : [How to warn about class (name) deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008444/how-to-warn-about-class-name-deprecation)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if I have set of classes moved? Do I need to create all methods?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this simple solution :

```
class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        # prints a warning message in the console
        print('The "Model" class has been moved to b.py, please consider modifying your code !')

m = Model() # instantiate the model class to throw the message
```

This should work like you expected it
Edit: this is the code for a.py