# Renaming of functions with preservation of backward compatibility

Tags: python, refactoring

I refactor my old code and want to change the names of functions in accordance with pep8. But I want to maintain backward compatibility with old parts of system (a complete refactoring of the project is impossible because function names is a part of the API and some users use the old client code).

Simple example, old code:

```
def helloFunc(name):
    print 'hello %s' % name
```

New:

```
def hello_func(name):
    print 'hello %s' % name
```

But both functions should work:

```
>>hello_func('Alex')
>>'hello Alex'
>>helloFunc('Alf')
>>'hello Alf'
```

I'm thinking about:

```
def helloFunc(name):
    hello_func(name)
```

, but I do not like it (in project about 50 functions, and it will look a messy, I think).

What is the best way to do it(excluding duplication ofcource)? Is it possible the creation of a some universal decorator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that for the time being, the easiest thing is to just create a new reference to the old function object:

```
def helloFunc():
    pass

hello_func = helloFunc
```

Of course, it would probably be more *slightly* more clean if you changed the name of the actual function to `hello_func` and then created the alias as:

```
helloFunc = hello_func
```

This is still a little messy because it clutters your module namespace unnecessarily.  To get around that, you could also have a submodule that provides these "aliases".  Then, for your users, it would be as simple as changing `import module` to `import module.submodule as module`, but you don't clutter your module namespace.

You could probably even use `inspect` to do something like this automagically (untested):

```
import inspect
import re
def underscore_to_camel(modinput,modadd):
    """
       Find all functions in modinput and add them to modadd.  
       In modadd, all the functions will be converted from name_with_underscore
       to camelCase
    """
    functions = inspect.getmembers(modinput,inspect.isfunction)
    for f in functions:
        camel_name = re.sub(r'_.',lambda x: x.group()[1].upper(),f.__name__)
        setattr(modadd,camel_name,f)
```

Comment: @vlad -- I've added a function which I think will automatically add `function_with_underscores` from module `modinput` onto `modadd` as `functionWithUnderscores` (but it won't really work with `lambda` functions as they have no inspectable name (AFAIK)

Comment: Thanks for `setattr`! That was obviously the way.

Answer (score 9):

While the other answers are definitely true, it could be useful to rename the function to the new name and create an old one which emits a warning:

```
def func_new(a):
    do_stuff()

def funcOld(a):
    import warnings
    warnings.warn("funcOld should not be called any longer.")
    return func_new(a)
```

Comment: better yet, use `warnings.warn('description', DeprecationWarning)` to explicitly note that this calling conversion is deprecated

Answer (score 4):

You can bind your function object to another name in your module's namespace, e.g:

```
def funcOld(a):
    return a

func_new = funcOld
```

Answer (score 2):

As your question sounds very much like deprecation or similar, I'd like to strongly recommend the use of decorators for cleaner code. In fact, someone in another thread has already [created this for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30253848/1283083).