# Two class methods were same functionally but got an different name

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

When using redis sorted set, I want to make class methods more readable. In redis-py, especially in sorted set, `push` and `update` operation work same. For example,

```
class A(object):
    def push(self, key, value, score):
        return redis.zadd(key, {value: score})

    def update(self, key, value, score):
        return self.push(key, value, score)

if __name__ == 'main':
    a = A()
    # push item1 in redis sorted set
    a.push('sorted_set', 'item1', 1)

    # update item1 in redis sorted set to score 2
    # but I also know that this is same with
    # a.push('sorted_set', 'item1', 2)
    a.update('sorted_set', 'item1', 2)
```

However, I wondering that there is better way to solve this issue. Please let me know.

Comment: stop using python 2.7 it's going to be deprecated

Comment: @andreihondrari , if i use python 3.x then what benefits were exist to solve this issue?

Comment: you avoid a future problem

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen this use, so this might not be "recommended", but technically you can do this.

```
class A(object):
    def push(self, key, value, score):
        return redis.zadd(key, {value: score})

    update = push
```

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11987065/8557739).

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I met function re-naming and backward comparability for the first time as a keyword.