# How to catch an AttributeError in Background through Decorator?

Tags: python, attributeerror

this is raising an AttributeError in the moment:

```
from functions import *

class Class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Name'

    @exception_handler
    def do_stuff(self):
        print('Stuff')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Class()
    test.dooo_stuff()
```

> AttributeError: 'Class' object has no attribute 'dooo_stuff'

I want to catch this Attribute Error somehow with an Decorator in Background. So that i can inform the user that the class method name has changed.

So

```
try:  
    test = Class()
    test.dooo_stuff()
except AttributeError:
    print('info')
```

will not work because that is not in Background. I want to change the Error Message above to notify the user.
Is there any way to do that?
Thanks

Comment: Not sure if I completely understand the question, but have you checked out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30253848/15282257)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#data-model) is very powerfull. You can [customize attribute access](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access) with the dunder method [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) :

> Called when the default attribute access fails with an AttributeError [...] This method should either return the (computed) attribute value or raise an AttributeError exception.

Although the usual usage is to provide dynamic values (that is how [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) or [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) are implemented for example), it is possible to execute any code we want, for example calling a callback :

```py
def handler(attribute_error_name):
    print(f"{attribute_error_name!r} does not exist")


class MyAPI:
    def do_stuff(self):
        return "done"

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        handler(item)
        return lambda: None  # if the return value is not callable, we get TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

api = MyAPI()
print(api.do_stuff())
print(api.do_something_else())
```

outputs

```
done
'do_something_else' does not exist
None
```

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you very much!